# Can I use bootstrapping technique to get a 95% conf. interval of conversion rate

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, confidence-interval, bootstrap

I have a sample data about user conversion at an ecommerce site. The data contains the following variables:

- User Id
- Site visits - count of the number of times the user visited the site during the relevant period
- Purchases count - count of the number of times the user purchased anything from the site (every time the user checks-out)

I would like to calculate conversion rate for each user. That part is obviously easy:
`conversion_rate = purchase_count/site_visits`

My question is, given that I have conversion rate for each user, and it's not a continues number, can I bootstrap it to get a 95% conf. interval?

My plan is to use the following code:

```
  data$conversion_rate = data$purchase_count/data$site_visits
  samples_conversion_rate = numeric(1000)
  for (i in 1:1000){
    samp = sample(data$conversion_rate, size = length(data), replace = TRUE)
    samples_conversion_rate[i] = mean(samp, na.rm = T)
  }
  lb = quantile(samples_conversion_rate, 0.025)
  ub = quantile(samples_conversion_rate, 0.975)
```

Would that work?

Comment: For sure No, unless you define `x`. More generally, you might consider your method of finding `lb` and `ub`.

Comment: @BruceET What do you mean? I defined x. Would that make since now?

Comment: Looks better now. Will try running the code with a fake vector later.

Comment: OK. I ran your code (or as near to it as feasible) and all seems well now that you have corrected the last couple of lines. // Generally, we do not check the validity of code here. However, you raise some questions whether bootstrapping is appropriate here, and I have tried to answer some of them in my Answer.

Answer (score 1):

Because I don't have access to your data, I substituted a vector `x`,
consisting of 2000 values from the distribution $\mathsf{Beta}(2, 18),$
rounded to three places. The population mean is $\mu = 0.1$ and its support
is $(0,1).$ [For more on beta distributions, see the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution).]

[image]

Although constrained to the unit interval, this beta distribution is heavily right-skewed. Here is a boxplot of the data in `x`, showing many outliers towards the right. I have no idea whether these data are similar to yours, but
they should suffice for a demonstration.

[image]

```
set.seed(1120);  x = round(rbeta(2000, 2, 18), 3)       # my fake data

## data$conversion_rate = data$purchase_count/data$site_visits
samples_conversion_rate = numeric(1000)
for (i in 1:1000){
  samp = sample(x, size = length(x), replace = TRUE)    # statement modified
  samples_conversion_rate[i] = mean(samp, na.rm = T)mean
}
lb = quantile(samples_conversion_rate, 0.025)
ub = quantile(samples_conversion_rate, 0.975)
lb; ub
      2.5% 
0.09756694 
    97.5% 
0.1032916 
length(unique(samples_conversion_rate))
[1] 950

hist(samples_conversion_rate, prob=T, br=25, col="skyblue2")
abline(v=c(lb,ub), col="red", lwd=2, lty="dotted")
```

[image]

The resulting 95% nonparametric bootstrap CI is $(0.098, 0.103),$ which
contains the population mean $\mu = 0.1$ (knowable because my data are simulated).

Comments on the procedure.

(1) You are treating all customers equally,
regardless of the dollar amount of their purchases. Depending on your
assumptions and purposes, this may or may not be a good idea.

(2) Your style of bootstrap CI is not bias corrected. If your distribution
of conversion rates is heavily skewed (as for my fake data), it might be better to use a bias-corrected bootstrap. However here, the histogram of re-sampled values is
nearly symmetrical, so bias correction does not seem crucial.

(3) You mention that your data are not continuous. I don't believe that is
a problem. However, with discrete data it is a good idea to make sure
that the re-samples take many different values. In this case it's 950
uniquely different values out of 1000 --- not surprising because my data
were simulated to three places.

(4) Bootstrapping was invented something like 30 years ago when computing
was not as fast and cheap as now. So it became standard to use 1000 re-samples.
Thus the bootstrap CI may differ noticeably from one run to another. 
Nowadays, I like to use 10,000 or 100,000 iterations for less variability.
(However, in most cases this would not make a difference for practical
purposes.)